# updated versions of jjwt are not available in maven repository

Tags: java, jjwt

Latest version available on Maven repo is 0.9.1.  However github shows activity and releases in the last two years and latest release per github is 0.11.1.  Is there a shift in policy to publish releases to Maven?  Or does it happen on a different schedule?

Thanks
Pat Malay

Answer (score 0):

jjwt was reorganized into a multi-module project [since 0.10.0](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/348).
Look into [Installation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#install) section for details.
All the actual versions [available in Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken) as well.